# Incoming call notification will be missed when i swap the incoming call notification using flutter_callkeep

Tags: flutter, dart

When I receive the call notification, I skip the notification by swapping up, the call will be missed.

I want that I should not be able to swipe up or something that keep user pushes that this notification can't be skipped as same as WhatsApp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.